# STM32H7 SPI Nor Flash Device is always busy IS25LP128F

Tags: c, embedded

I am working on SPI Nor Flash IC IS25LP128F using Little FS as my file system.  I Set 400Mhz as SPI kernel Clock, and my Prescaler value at 8. Hence 50 MHz SPI clock runs.  At this case, my Filesystem operation takes places successfully at time, some times the code hangs in the SPI routine for a long time and states, NOR Device is busy.

According to Datasheet 80Mhz SPI clock, normal Read and 166Mhz SPI clock  Fast read is given for IS25LP128F. I changed the kernel clk, to get respective output clock. Even then, the problem remains the same.

At 50Mhz sometimes to write a single line(64 byte) takes 4 minutes to complete. I have tried with 100Mhz, 80Mhz, 50Mhz, all the prescaler values, but only for 50 Mhz runs successfully sometimes (not all the time success)

Without device busy(txData=0 has to come), the filesystem, have to be taken place.

Pls help me out.
[image]
[Datasheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukwWq.png)
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xw9La.png)

```
/*Received Txdata always busy*/
uint8_t readStatusReg(void)
{
    uint8_t txData;
    CS_ACTIVE;
    txData=CMD_RDSR;
    HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, &txData, 1, 1000);
    while(HAL_SPI_GetState(&hspi1) != HAL_SPI_STATE_READY);
    HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi1,  &txData, 1, 1000);
    CS_DEACTIVE;
    return txData;
}

/*Clock Config */
static void HWI_SPI1_Init(void)
{
    /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI1_Init 0 */

    /* USER CODE END SPI1_Init 0 */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI1_Init 1 */

    /* USER CODE END SPI1_Init 1 */
    /* SPI1 parameter configuration*/

    hspi1.Instance = SPI1;
    hspi1.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
    hspi1.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
    hspi1.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
    hspi1.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_HIGH;
    hspi1.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_2EDGE;
    hspi1.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
    hspi1.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_4;   
    hspi1.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
    hspi1.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
    hspi1.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
    hspi1.Init.CRCPolynomial = 7;
    hspi1.Init.NSSPMode = SPI_NSS_PULSE_ENABLE;

}
```

Comment: On STM32H7 spi_ker_clk maximum frequency is 200Mhz (so with a prescaler set to 8 your SPI clock is at 25Mhz maximum). How did you set up your clocks ?

Comment: SPI clock after prescaler of 8 is 50 Mhz(SPI clock). Hence 8*50=400Mhz Input to SPI clk.

Comment: if you say so, good for you. But if I were you I would double check the peripheral clock limitations and the clock tree setup (which can be pretty complicated on this product).